# Placing $HOME directory on nfs server

Tags: login, home-directory, nfs

I have a number of client machines, all running Ubuntu, and recently upgraded to 13.04.  I also have a Slackware-based server which includes an nfs service.

What I am aiming to do is to have access to all my documents from any client.  I have copied my entire `$HOME` directory to the fileserver.  I have used `usermod -d` to set my home directory to the appropriate area on the server.  I use `autofs` to mount remote directories, so the full path is `/net/tower/mnt/user/UserHome/peter`.

If I log in via a text console, all is fine - my files are accessible and writable.  However, if I log in via desktop, I get an error:

```
Could not update ICEauthority file with the full path/filename for the .ICEauthority file.
```

I have ensured that ownership and priveledges/permissions on the file are correct.  I have tried deleting the file, I have tried creating an empty file from a text console - I still get the error.

Either I have to find a way of getting past this error, or find a way to change my `$HOME` after login (from my `.profile`?).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do realize that if the NFS is not reachable your system will -not- boot?  I would never consider your method and would  advice to store the directory `~/Documents` on that server and not `/home` itself. That way your system will always boot and the files (like .ICEauthority) will remain as they should be.

Comment: I don't understand why the system should not boot.  Surely the $HOME directory structure is different for each user, and only comes into play when the user logs in?  Each machine would retain at least one administrator account with its $HOME directory on the boot disk.  Are you saying that it's not viable to keep a centralised home directory for an individual user, which will be accessed whichever client computer is used to login?

Comment: Nope. If /home does not get mounted from /etc/fstab it will halt. "Are you saying that it's not viable to keep a centralised home directory for an individual user, which will be accessed whichever client computer is used to login?" No, I am saying that mounting a /home from another server is not good practice. I would advice to mount ~/Documents if all you care for is a central Document folder or mount a shared directory (the latter is the normal method).

Comment: I'm sorry to be so stupid, but I really do not understand " If /home does not get mounted from /etc/fstab it will halt."  I have no problem with /home being mounted at boot time, and that would contain, at least, the $HOME directory structure for the system administrator.  However,what I was hoping to achieve was for the home directory structure of other users to be located elsewhere. This can, after all, be achieved by 'usermod -d'.  If this 'elsewhere' happens to be on an nfs server, should the system care?

Comment: What I am trying to do certainly works for a text console login, but fails for a gnome login.  You have given me an idea, though - perhaps I need to add the remote home directory device to the fstab .. at the moment it is only being mounted by autofs.

Comment: For the record, I think this idea is cool. I'm trying to accomplish this through livecd's and symlinks; boot from the live cd, symlink `/home` straight to the nfs share, reboot. I'm 90% there.

Answer (score 5):

My advice won't solve all your problems, but you may find it enough. You could have only a bunch of directories in the NFS server. i.e., the Documents directory. To do so, mount your nfs server home somewhere like `/media/nfs_server/home`. Then change the contents of the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

There you can change the Documents default dir and set it to your NFS server home:

You should have something like:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
```

Change it to:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/nfs_server/home/my_login/Documents"
```

Replace it to where you really mount your NFS server and your real login. You could even try something like: `/media/nfs_server/$HOME/Documents`, but it depends of your server directories.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method will work and does not touch the files directly residing in /home/$USER (ie. the hidden files). Though I myself would use a shared directory (ie. a mountpoint `/share` for instance).